# In Presto/Athena, how to filter out in WHERE clause those records that fail type CAST

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

In my Presto/Athena query, I want to be able to filter out records that fail on a CAST (eg. cast as bigint or as double).

Is there a more concise way of doing it without having to use TRY_CAST in a nested query and filter records that have null for those fields in an outer query?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to filter out records that fail on a CAST (eg. cast as bigint or as double).

Use [`try_cast`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#try_cast), or [`try`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try) + `CAST`.

> Is there a more concise way of doing it without having to use TRY_CAST in a nested query and filter records that have null for those fields in an outer query?

There isn't a simpler way, except that you can place `try` / `try_cast` in the `WHERE` clause directly:

```
WHERE try(CAST(col AS bigint)) IS NULL
```